# Java:jasper report remove trailing zeros

Tags: java, string, jasper-reports

I have a report I have used floor function to get my result but the result gives out decimals `2.0` and I just want to get the whole number like `2`.

This is my formula I used to get my result.

```
FLOOR(DAYS(DATE(new Integer($F{date_last_modified}.getYear()+1900),new Integer($F{date_last_modified}.getMonth()+1),new Integer($F{date_last_modified}.getDate())),DATE(2013,05,20))/7)+" "+"weeks "+DAYS(DATE(new Integer($F{date_last_modified}.getYear()+1900),new Integer($F{date_last_modified}.getMonth()+1),new Integer($F{date_last_modified}.getDate())),DATE(2013,05,20) ) % 7 +" "+"days"+" ago"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `cast` your formula to `Integer` as

```
(int) YourFormula
```

Then for your formula the code will be

```
(int) (FLOOR(DAYS(DATE(new Integer($F{date_last_modified}.getYear()+1900),new Integer($F{date_last_modified}.getMonth()+1),new Integer($F{date_last_modified}.getDate())),DATE(2013,05,20))/7)+" "+"weeks "+DAYS(DATE(new Integer($F{date_last_modified}.getYear()+1900),new Integer($F{date_last_modified}.getMonth()+1),new Integer($F{date_last_modified}.getDate())),DATE(2013,05,20) ) % 7 +" "+"days"+" ago")
```

Comment: Thank for your response but i get an expression error on my jasper report. seems not to like the `(int)`.Am mainly focusing on this section of my formula.
`DAYS(DATE(new Integer($F{date_last_modified}.getYear()+1900),new Integer($F{date_last_modified}.getMonth()+1),new Integer($F{date_last_modified}.getDate())),DATE(2013,05,20))/7)`

Comment: @saiyan101 What is exactly the expression error that output for you ??

Comment: This the error i get:`net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression : 
 Source text : (int)(FLOOR(DAYS(DATE(new Integer($F{date_last_modified}.getYear()+1900),new Integer($F{date_last_modified}.getMonth()+1),new Integer($F{date_last_modified}.getDate())),DATE(2013,05,20))/7)+" "+"weeks "+DAYS(DATE(new Integer($F{date_last_modified}.getYear()+1900),new Integer($F{date_last_modified}.getMonth()+1),new Integer($F{date_last_modified}.getDate())),DATE(2013,05,20) ) % 7 +" "+"days"+ " ago")`

Comment: Please determine what is the type of your result by show us  `Expression Class` value ?